# Div::after making page have opacity

Tags: html, css

I have css sheet that keeps making one of my webpages have the same opacity as the background image, but it doesn't do it to the others. I don't want the whole page to have the opacity, just the background. I've played around with it but I'm not exactly sure why it's doing it to this page in particular. The only thing that's different is that this page has a table, the others either have a form or don't have one. Let me know if I should share some of the html. 
The css that's causing it:

```
 div::after {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(brain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Added html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function display() {
            document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pname").value;
            document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("rname").value;
            document.getElementById("rname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("kname").value;
            document.getElementById("kname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("hname").value;
            document.getElementById("hname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea5").innerHTML = document.getElementById("oname").value;
            document.getElementById("oname").value = "";
        }
    </script>
    <link href="general.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="horizontal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="formpage1.html">Quiz page 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <article>
            <h1>Goal Setting</h1>
            <p></p>
        </article>
    </header>
    <table bgcolor="#FF00FF" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Goal</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Plan</td>
            <td><input type="text" name=pname" id="pname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goal</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="rname" id="rname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Plan</td>
            <td><input type="text" name=kname" id="kname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goal</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="hname" id="hname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Plan</td>
            <td><input type="text" name=oname" id="oname"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display(event)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="400px" align="center" border=0>

        <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
            <td align="center"><b>Goal</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Plan</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Goal</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Plan</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Goal</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Plan</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea1"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea2"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea3"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea4"></div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div id="displayarea5"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So bottom pic is what it looks like right now, it shares the same opacity as the background but I only want the background to have it, not the content. The above pic is what another page looks like, I want it to look like that.[image][image]

Comment: Add your HTML too

Comment: Is the HTML for the web-page which doesn't behave correctly?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve? Maybe include a screenshot of the desired outcome you want.

Comment: You should share enough HTML and CSS to allow us to reproduce the issue. Using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) is a good way of achieving that. Do note that you have a number of missing parentheses in your HTML, and you're using deprecated appearance-related attributes (`bgcolor`, `align`) that could be interfering with your CSS.

Comment: With `div::after` you've literally added pseudo element to every possible div on your page. It's extremely bad practice. First of all, if you just want a background, I don't see any reason to do it with pseudo element when you have `background-image` in CSS. If for some reason you MUST use pseudo `::after` use it on a specific element (ideally target it with a class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jackie, it's not making everything transparent, but the image is actually **above** your page content, thus making it look opaque as well. Your solution is to set `z-index` of `::after` pseudoelement to -1.

```
div::after {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(brain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

But like I said in the comment, I would highly suggest that you target very specific element with a class on it, instead of applying `::after` to every directly to `div` element.